# Python: how to open folder of a file and point to it

Tags: python, macos, path

At the end of my python script I want to open the folder (location) of a generated file (not the file itself) and have the cursor point at it (similar to when showing a file in a folder in Finder):

The generated file path is in the variable `output_path`, but when I do this:

```
os.system("open " + output_path)
```

The file, and not the location, opens. How to modify it so it does what I aim to do?

Comment: you probably want to use [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which has excellent path handling and to call Finder to open where you would like

Comment: You could also use `os.path.dirname(output_path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.dirname()` to get the directory name from a pathname. Also, use `shlex.quote()` to escape any special characters before using this with `os.system()`.

```
import shlex
import os

os.system("open " + shlex.quote(os.path.dirname(output_path))
```

Comment: Thanks, however "module 'shlex' has no attribute 'escape"

Comment: Sorry, I confused `shlex.escape` with `shlex.quote()`.